# Tomcat in Eclipse remains starting/synchronized but is actually running

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I'm having the following problem with Eclipse 3.7 and Tomcat 7.0.8: I've added my Tomcat with a deployment descriptor in my Eclipse. I've enabled "Use Tomcat installation" in the server settings and tried to start it. The Console in Eclipse says "Server started up in 70s", I can access my application, but the servers state remains "Starting/Synchronized". As a result sooner or later the configured timeout is triggered and I'm getting an error.

Why is Eclipse not recognizing that the server was started successfully?

I've also tried to reinstall Eclipse and Tomcat - no positive changes.
Also adding a clean, fresh downloaded Tomcat results in the same "error".

Any suggestions?
Richard

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/12745589/677381 this solved this same situation for me

Answer (score 4):

Try changing the HTTP port from the server configuration screen. For example if you previously had 8080, try changing it to 8090. This should automatically update the new port number to server.xml.

[image: server configuraton]

I started running into the same problem after I had been modifying the server port directly in server.xml. Changing the ports back to what they had been did not seem to solve the problem. It looked like the server pluging and actual configuration got somehow out of sync.

Comment: This worked for Neon.1 and Tomcat 7. I could not change the port back to 8080, seems to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

Steps That I tried and get project up and running.

1. Delete Eclipse Tomcat
2. Reconfigure It
3. Add tomcat to Build path
4. Project -> Clean
5. Tomcat -> Clean
6. Run the Project